# Solr 5 memory management

Tags: java, solr, solrj

We are using solr 5 over tomcat and we are facing an issue while updating a Solr index using SolrJ.

The issue is that the memory ("Working set") of the tomcat process keeps increasing until it exceeds the maximum assigned JVM memory "-Xmx" rather than the "Memory - private working set" doesn't exceeds the assigned "-Xmx", even after the index is updated and replicated to the Slave nodes and the Solr tomcat process is idle, it keeps allocating the memory and the garbage collector doesn't clear this assigned memory.

We made some changes in our environment by running our Master Solr node on a Jetty container instead of Tomcat container and we decreased the assigned "-Xmx" to 20GB instead of 35GB, but it didn't fix the issue.

Please help.

Comment: Running Solr under Tomcat isn't supported from Solr5 and onwards, but how are you importing? Have you checked where the memory is leaked (i.e. which generation)? Are you using the server for querying as well? Does it consume any memory if you're not indexing?

Comment: What is the GC setting are you using CMS or default throughput mode? solr is well tuned for CMS setting

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for your reply, I agree with you that Running Solr under Tomcat isn't supported from Solr5, and we intend to run it under Jetty, but before we move to this step, we are trying to optimize Tomcat to run Solr5 without any memory issues.
Anyway, we are currently importing (indexing) data using SolrJ (JAVA API) and we don't use this server for querying, we just use it for indexing data, in addition, we use this server as a Master Solr node which then replicates multiple Slave Solr nodes.

Comment: @MatsLindh We also noticed that during the Slave nodes are replicating from the Master node (which has the issue), their are some memory consumed in the "Windows Task Manager" but not like during indexing.
The current memory configuration for the Tomcat (Master Solr) is "-Xms = 2048 MB" &"-Xmx = 35000 MB".

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing that the JVM allocates the memory it has been allowed, and using it as a cache for as long as necessary? Anyway - optimizing for an outdated version of Solr and a non-supported configuration seems like a lot of work you'll have to redo. In addition, memory shown as allocated under Task Manager might be in multiple different pools, including being used as a cache or shared among processes.

Comment: @MatsLindh The below are the complete memory configuration which we set to the JVM of the Tomcat (Master Solr).

-Xms2048m
-Xmx35000m
-XX:PermSize=1024M
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=25

Comment: @Ganesh According to the above configuration, I think the GC setting which we are using is CMS.

Comment: So you're telling the JVM that its OK to keep up to 35G of memory allocated, so it probably does. There is no need to invoke garbage collection or reduce allocated memory until you actually need it. Have you checked what the JVM itself says about memory usage? Are you getting Out of memory exceptions? [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) can tell you about the current state of the JVM and its allocated memory.

Comment: Somewhat related: 35GB is just about the worst Xmx you can possibly use. Try 31GB instead: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/

Comment: @TokeEskildsen please check my reply below, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty normal for heap memory to go up to the maximum provided, that is not a problem. Just that when it has to reclaim the memory you might encounter a pause time (translates to slowness in query response time) more that what you would if the allocated memory size was smaller.

Do you really need 35GB? use this estimating mechanism to sizing for  your data. There is also handy excel sheet for you to estimate the needed memory size.

https://lucidworks.com/2011/09/14/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/

Comment: Dear All, we made some changes in our environment by running our Master Solr node on a Jetty container instead of Tomcat and we decreased the assigned "-Xmx" to 20GB instead of 35GB. - TO BE CONTINUED

Comment: And after deep investigation, we found in the Windows Task Manager) that the Solr replication dramatically increases the "Memory - working set" until it exceeds the assigned "-Xmx", while the "Memory - private working set" increases normally and doesn't exceed 60% from the assigned memory in the "-Xmx" which sounds that the GC runs correctly on the "Memory - private working set" while it doesn't run correctly on the "Memory - working set" even after the replication is finished, it doesn't free more that 30% from the allocated memory.  - TO BE CONTINUED

Comment: By the way we have Solr indexes which its size is 120GB which is sometimes fully replicated, i.e. after the replication is finished, the "lastCycleBytesDownloaded" of this index equals 120GB.

Comment: The working set includes mapped pages, so if your index is > physical memory, the working set should be whatever physical memory your Solr process can get its hands on. No worries, you want it to do so as it is just caching, which will be freed if the system needs the mem: http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html